# Discord.js and Discordx VoiceStateUpdate returns undefined

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

When I try to get the user id, channel and other data, I get `undefined` in response instead of data

```js
import { VoiceState } from "discord.js";
import { Discord, On } from "discordx";

@Discord()
export class VoiceStateUpdate {
  @On()
  voiceStateUpdate(oldState: VoiceState, newState: VoiceState): void {
    console.log(oldState.id)
    console.log(newState.id)
    console.log(oldState.channelId)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you would need to use `@On({ event: "voiceStateUpdate" })` (see https://discordx.js.org/docs/discordx/decorators/general/on)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

In your main.ts, where the bot is created
Do you have the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent ?

```js
import { VoiceState } from "discord.js";
import { Discord, On } from "discordx";

@Discord()
export class VoiceStateUpdate {
  @On()
  voiceStateUpdate([oldState, newState]: ArgsOf<"voiceStateUpdate">): void {
    console.log(oldState.id)
    console.log(newState.id)
    console.log(oldState.channelId)
  }
}
```

Let me know if it's working :)